# Bootsrap 4 input text as readonly responsive using Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create the input text as read-only using the bootstrap.

I found from the bootstrap link we can use **form-control-plaintext** class

```
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
```

if the value is long on the input the text is not responsive. I need to make the text responsive as well.

How do I achieve that ?

Comment: can you add a snippet that can recreate this issue please?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ie7gxx Please refer to this

Comment: why not use a `textarea` ?

Comment: Text area doen't solve the issue

Comment: so, if the value is too long, what do you expect? the break down to the next line or go hidden?

Comment: Break down to the next line. If I used the TextArea it add scroll I don't want to add scroll

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help you

In controller

```
autogrow(){
  let  textArea = document.getElementById("textarea")       
  textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  textArea.style.height = '0px';
  textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

and in html

```
<textarea id="textarea" (keyup)="autogrow()" ></textarea>
```

Comment: That creates a scroll bar

Comment: @SanJaisy you can hide its scroll by using `overflow: hidden;``min-height: 20px;` `max-height: 100px;` and also `resize:none`

Comment: Did you try `overflow:auto`  instead of `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @SanJaisy Try my updated code now its works exactly what you want sorry for prev ans.

Comment: Can you please update the angular version of that. I am using angular 8.

Comment: Opss you didn't mention in question that you are using angular 8 :(

Comment: Also can please use either input or textarea, because have to use input or textarea

Comment: Updated my ans may be that will help u

Comment: can't use the class="form-control-plaintext" and text are not responsive

Comment: Then may be you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-autosize)  or  [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-textarea-autosize) will help you